# UWP on windows 10 IoT

Tags: windows, raspberry-pi, uwp, iot, windows-10-iot-core

I have a UWP application that run on raspberry that handles some stuff.

There is no display connected to Raspberry nor can't be. But few times a day there is a need to change some settings or access application log. I want to connect to device and manage it wirelessly by phone. I know there is a app for Windows 10, but majority of users have Android/iOS.

My idea was to run UWP and asp.Net web application simoutanously on Raspberry. Is it possible?

Or is there any other way to do it?

Thank you for your answers and ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> > My idea was to run UWP and asp.Net web application simoutanously on Raspberry. Is it possible?

1. Windows IoT core does not support .Net Framework. So full-wing ASP.NET is NOT supported on Windows IoT Core.
2. ASP.NET Core is supported by Windows ARM, but it's still in beta.

   ASP.NET Core is part of .NET Core, so .NET Core should be installed on PC and ASP.NET Core Web Application needs Windows arm platform to run on raspberry pi. However the Daily Builds of ASP.NET Core is still in a beta version.
3. UWP and ASP.NET Core CAN be run simultaneously on Windows IoT Core.

   The UWP application can be run on Windows IoT core and ASP.NET Core Web Application can be run on ASP.NET Core. So UWP application and Web Application can be run simultaneously.

Link:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/cesardelatorre/2016/06/27/net-core-1-0-net-framework-xamarin-the-whatand-when-to-use-it/

https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/core#/current

https://github.com/dotnet/core-setup

https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/issues/7899

https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot/samples/helloworld